# Can't get alert pop-up to work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this simple uploader that uploads a chosen file in a folder, I use PHP, HTML and MSSQL as my database. The pop-up script doesn't work everytime I have successfully uploaded the file. What seems to be the problem? here is a part of my code:

```
 //move_uploaded_file function will upload your image.  if you want to resize image before uploading see this link http://b2atutorials.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-upload-and-resize-image-for.html

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\Pics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
  // If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
  $query_image = "insert into dbo.acc_images (image, status, acc_id) values ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."', 'display','')";

  if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_image))
  {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Stored in: " . "\Users\Joseph\Desktop\Pics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);</script>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'File name not stored in database';
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The pop-up message that suppose to pop-up does not work; by the way I use google chrome as my wamp's default browser.

Comment: Does it gobble up your browser?  Send you a frowny face?  Throw an error?  Not exist in the source code?  Create a wormhole into the depths of a binary bit?  "Does not work" is really an explanation that does not work and makes it very hard to help. :)

Comment: It now works, there was a problem in the string concatenation in the echo message. :)

Comment: That was **not** your problem.  That was the solution to the problem.  The problem was that you had a `"` in your string in Javascript.  That was caused by your concatentation error.  The error you would have received in your browser, which I was trying to get you to share, would have led you to that.  The accepted answer tells you the fix, but not why it is *really* the fix or how you could have found that yourself.  So, without that information, you'll find yourself stuck again without the knowledge to dig yourself out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string concatenation is wrong, and it's breaking your javascript.

Try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Stored in: \Users\Joseph\Desktop\Pics/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . '");</script>';
```